# OpenLayers: keep showing WebGl tiles when the source changes

Tags: javascript, webgl, openlayers

We use the OpenLayers library to show raster tiles with weather-related data in the foreground, with a background consisting of OpenStreetMap tiles. The user can select tiles for different timestamps. Switching the timestamp switches the URL via the method TileImage.setUrl.

The problem is that when using setUrl, the weather-related tiles disappear immediately and only the OSM background is shown before the new tiles are downloaded. This is contrary to an older OpenLayers version, where old WebGl tiles were shown even after running setUrl, before being replaced by the new tiles.

Is there a simple way how to keep showing the old tiles just before the new one loads, so that some tiles are always visible in the foreground?

Simplified, the code works as follows:

```js
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/WebGLTile.js';
import View from 'ol/View.js';
import TileImage from 'ol/source/TileImage.js';

let urlA = "https://www.example.com/temperature.php?tile_x={x}&tile_y={y}&tile_zoom={z}&datetime=now";
let urlB = "https://www.example.com/temperature.php?tile_x={x}&tile_y={y}&tile_zoom={z}&datetime=now+1hour";
let urlC = "https://www.example.com/temperature.php?tile_x={x}&tile_y={y}&tile_zoom={z}&datetime=now+2hours";

const src = new TileImage({url: urlA});


const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
    new TileLayer({
         source: src,
    }),
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0,
  }),
});

document.getElementById("tempA").addEventListener("click", e => {
     src.setUrl(urlA);
     e.preventDefault();
})
document.getElementById("tempB").addEventListener("click", e => {
     src.setUrl(urlB);
     e.preventDefault();
})
document.getElementById("tempC").addEventListener("click", e => {
     src.setUrl(urlC);
     e.preventDefault();
})
```